# VirtualBox 5.2 on Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan

Tags: virtualbox

After upgrading to 19.10 VirtualBox will not start any virtual machines because the drivers fail to build. VirtualBox prompts you to run '/sbin/vboxconfig', which fails because their code isn't compatible with the 5.3.0 kernel.

Comment: you tried to downgrade the VirtualBox version?

Comment: Easier way should be upgrading to 6.0.14 from eoan repository.

Answer (score 2):

There is a patch for the VirtualBox code here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/pipermail/vbox-dev/2019-July/015297.html

It patches the following files:
/usr/share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/mp-r0drv-linux.c
/usr/share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c

After applying the patch (which required some manual work for me), I ran 'sudo /sbin/vboxconfig' and everything worked.

Comment: That looks like too much work! Is there a stable PPA for virtual box in 19.10?